# JavaScript: check if date A is at most 3 times earlier/late than date B

Tags: javascript, date, validation

I have to write a JavaScript function that checks if two dates (formatted `dd/MM/yyyy`) make a time interval of at most 3 months.

I can retrieve the two values from two textboxes (no need to check formatting, I have been given a calendar control that automatically formats the date correctly).

I have almost no experience with JavaScript. Can you help me?

Examples:

15/2/2011, 13/2/2011 -> return true
6/1/2011, 5/10/2010 -> return false

I already check that date A is later than date B (the calendar does it for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a ton of code:

```
function days_between(date1, date2) {
    return Math.round(Math.abs(date1 - date2) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) > 90;
}
```

`date1` and `date2` are [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date) objects e.g.

```
 var date1 = new Date('mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find difference between two dates and return value accordingly.

```
function days_between(date1, date2) {

    // The number of milliseconds in one day
    var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

    // Convert both dates to milliseconds
    var date1_ms = date1.getTime()
    var date2_ms = date2.getTime()

    // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
    var difference_ms = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms)

    // check converting back to days and return
    return (Math.round(difference_ms/ONE_DAY) >90);
}
```

If you are unable to check or parse date correctly then you should use

```
    var x=txtDate1.split("/");   //Here txtDate1 and txtDate2 are values from your textbox   
    var y=txtDate2.split("/");
  //date format(Fullyear,month,date) 

    var date1=new Date(x[2],(x[1]-1),x[0]);  
    var date2=new Date(y[2],(y[1]-1),y[0])
```

Comment: Hi, what type are date1 and date2? Are they strings that must be converted from dd/mm/yyyy? How do I make sure that Javascript is aware of the formatting? Thanks

Comment: The `if else` is more than superfluous, just return the already boolean result of `Math.round(...) > 90`

Comment: @djechelon - they are javascript variables of var type, but still if you get any parsing error then check update. You should accordingly create a date object parsing those strings.